# How to build chain of responsibility using constructor for initializing next chains?

Tags: java, chain-of-responsibility

How to build a chain of responsibility using constructor for initializing chains. 
Here is my Runner.class where i'm building my chain using **setNext**  method.

```
public class Runner {

private static final String ENTER_PATH = "Enter path: ";
private static final String FILTER_BY_NAME = "Filter by name? (0/1)";
private static final String ENTER_NAME_PARAMETER = "Enter name parameter please: ";
private static final String FILTER_BY_EXTENSION = "Filter by extension? (0/1)";
private static final String ENTER_EXTENSION_PARAMETER = "Enter extension please (without '.'): ";
private static final String FILTER_BY_SIZE = "Filter by size? (0/1)";
private static final String ENTER_SIZE_TO = "Enter upper limit searching files in kb";
private static final String ENTER_SIZE_FROM = "Enter lower limit searching files in kb";
private static final String TRUE="1";
private Scanner scanner;

private List<File> fileList;


public Runner() {
    this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.fileList = new ArrayList<>();
}

private String getDirName(){
    System.out.println(ENTER_PATH);
    return scanner.nextLine();
}


private Handler getChainOfResponsibility(){
    GeneralHandler generalHandler = new GeneralHandler();
    Handler lastHandler = generalHandler;


    System.out.println(FILTER_BY_NAME);
    if (scanner.nextLine().equals(TRUE)) {
        System.out.println(ENTER_NAME_PARAMETER);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        Handler nameHandler = new NameHandler(name);
        lastHandler.setHandler(nameHandler);
        lastHandler = nameHandler;
    }

    System.out.println(FILTER_BY_EXTENSION);
    if (scanner.nextLine().equals(TRUE)) {
        System.out.println(ENTER_EXTENSION_PARAMETER);
        Handler extensionHandler = new ExtensionHandler(scanner.nextLine());
        lastHandler.setHandler(extensionHandler);
        lastHandler = extensionHandler;
    }


    System.out.println(FILTER_BY_SIZE);
    if (scanner.nextLine().equals(TRUE)) {
        System.out.println(ENTER_SIZE_FROM);
        double fromSize = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(ENTER_SIZE_TO);
        double toSize = scanner.nextDouble();
        Handler sizeHandler = new SizeHandler(fromSize, toSize);
        lastHandler.setHandler(sizeHandler);
    }
    return generalHandler;
}


public void run() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    findAllFiles(getDirName(), getChainOfResponsibility());
    showListOfFilteredFiles();

}
```

Here is my Handler abstract class

```
    public abstract class Handler {

    private Handler handler;

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    protected abstract boolean handleFilter(File file);

    public boolean doFilter(File file){
        if(handleFilter(file)){
            if(Objects.nonNull(handler)){
                return handler.doFilter(file);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And also i have it's implementation. How to make, that it will be init through constructor! Help pls!

Answer (score 1):

### Preamble

Your implementation is wrong; the general way of implementing the [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) pattern is for each link in the chain to **forward the request to the next link if it cannot handle the request itself**. This is traditionally done by delegating to the abstract `super` class if the current class cannot handle the request. So in short, to comply with tradition, I would rewrite your `Handler` class as follows:

```
public abstract class Handler {
  private Handler next;

  public void setHandler(Handler next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public boolean doFilter(File file) {
    return next.doFilter(file);
  }
}
```

I have not read the contract of either your `Handler` nor `NameHandler` classes, but I'll just make a few assumptions in order to provide an example of how the `NameHandler` might look like after refactoring its parent:

```
public class NameHandler extends Handler {
  private final String name;

  public NameHandler(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean doFilter(File file){
    final boolean result;

    if(file.getName().equals(name)){
      result = true;
    }else{
      result = super.doFilter(file);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

### Answer

Use constructors to configure the next link in the chain as opposed to "setters" like your `setHandler` method:

```
public abstract class Handler {
  private final Handler next;

  public Handler(Handler next){
    this.next = next;
  }

  public boolean doFilter(File file){
    return next.doFilter(file);
  }
}
```

Now your subclasses are required to deal with the non-default constructor:

```
public class NameHandler extends Handler {
  private final String name;

  public NameHandler(String name, Handler next){
    super(next);
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean doFilter(File file){
    final boolean result;

    if(file.getName().equals(name)){
      result = true;
    }else{
      result = super.doFilter(file);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```